# Smack Android client fails to connect to ejabberd server

Tags: java, android, connection, ejabberd, smack

It's been more than 6 hours I'm stuck at this issue, I have checked hundreds of solutions over internet but nothing works for me.

I'm implementing an XMPP Android client via Smack 4.2, following are my gradle dependencies:

```
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.2.0"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.2.0"
```

I've declared permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Here is my code to connect to server

```
private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<UserProps, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(UserProps... props){
        try {
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.100.5");
            HostnameVerifier verifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            DomainBareJid serviceName = JidCreate.domainBareFrom("rabta");
            XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setUsernameAndPassword(props[0].getUser(), props[0].getPass())
                    .setHostAddress(addr)
                    .setXmppDomain(serviceName)
                    .setHostnameVerifier(verifier)
                    .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                    .setPort(5222)
                    .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                    .build();

            AbstractXMPPConnection conn = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
            conn.connect();
            if(conn.isConnected()) {
                Log.w("app", "connected--------------------------");
            }
            conn.login();

            if(conn.isAuthenticated()) {
                Log.w("app", "authenticated----------------------");
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }
}
```

Where `192.168.100.5` is the ipv4 address of windows 10 machine on which ejabberd is installed. `rabta` is the name of my server which I specified instead of `localhost` at the time of installation. My server is not on a live IP. My client and server, both are on same WiFi network.

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The following addresses failed: 'null:5222' failed because: /192.168.100.5
exception: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.100.5 (port 5222) after 30000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
01-05 05:16:19.757 18413-18591/com.rabta.rabta W/System.err: at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:617)
```

The message I receive on starting ejabberd

```
By default, the ejabberd Web Admin interface is enabled. You should be able to connect to the admin interface and log in with the user admin@rabta and the password you defined during the installation.
Users can connect to your server 'rabta' with any Jabber/XMPP
The name of the current ejabberd node is ejabberd@localhost.
```

User credentials to login: username `user1@rabta` password `pass`
and finally the ejabberd.yml

```
hosts:
  - "rabta"
listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    starttls: true
```

On server machine I have admin privileges and all the firewalls are turned off.
I'd be very glad If somebody could help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: whoever down voted my question should have spared some time to elaborate the reason for downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Use `Linux` instead of `Windows`

After lots of tries I found that there was nothing wrong with my client or server. The issue was with Windows.

When I checked ports and their listening processes from within the `Windows`, I could see `port:5222` being listened by `Erlang` but when I scanned the port from outside I realized that the port was closed. Tried every trick with firewall and network but no success.

Switched from `Windows` to `Linux` and everything works like a charm!